# Unable to manually add a SoapMessageHandler to SoapBinding

Tags: java, list, soap

For numerous reasons, I am trying to add a custom `SOAPHandler` manually on a `SOAPBinding`. This binding already have a `SOAPHandler` automatically wired, and I have to put another. My code is as such:

```
BindingProvider port = (BindingProvider) jaxProxyService;

// Configuration
port.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.HTTP_CLIENT_STREAMING_CHUNK_SIZE, 8192);
port.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.MTOM_THRESHOLOD_VALUE, 256);

SOAPBinding soapBinding = (SOAPBinding) port.getBinding();
soapBinding.setMTOMEnabled(true);

// DataHandlers are constructed before from files, not relevant to the issue I guess
final List<DataHandler> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
documentList.add(doc);

soapBinding.getHandlerChain().add(new CustomSoapMessageHandler(documentList));
```

My implementation goes as follow:

```
public class CustomSoapMessageHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private SOAPMessage soapMessage;
    private boolean outbound;
    private List<DataHandler> attachments;

    public CustomSoapMessageHandler() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomSoapMessageHandler(List<DataHandler> attachments) {
        super();
        this.attachments = attachments;
    }

    // Overriding handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext), handleFault(SOAPMessageContext), etc
```

When I get to the `add()` method, nothing happens. Debugger tells me that I successfully went through, I create my `CustomSoapMessageHandler` correctly, the `add` method returns **true**, but in the actual list of my `binding`, my Handler is not added at all. What happens here ? Is the list immutable / locked for some reason, or am I missing something on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

*First part:* If anyone encounters the same problem, a solution that works is to replace the whole `HandlerChain` manually. That way, you may be able to add other handlers manually:

```
// DataHandlers are constructed before from files, not relevant to the issue I guess
final List<DataHandler> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
documentList.add(doc);

final List<Handler> handlerList = new ArrayList<>();

// Don't forget to add the pre-loaded handlers
handlerList.addAll(soapBinding.getHandlerChain());
handlerList.add(new CustomSoapMessageHandler(documentList));

soapBinding.setHandlerChain(handlerList);
```

---

*Second part:* It does not work because the actual implementation of `getHandlerChain()` returns a copy of the actual `ArrayList`, not the list by itself. They protected the original with this, which prevents you from simply adding a `Handler` manually :

Binding.class:

```
 /**
 * Gets a copy of the handler chain for a protocol binding instance.
 * If the returned chain is modified a call to <code>setHandlerChain</code>
 * is required to configure the binding instance with the new chain.
 *
 *  @return java.util.List&lt;Handler> Handler chain
 */
public java.util.List<javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler> getHandlerChain();
```

BindingImpl.class:

```
public abstract class BindingImpl implements WSBinding {
    private HandlerConfiguration handlerConfig;

    ...

    public
    @NotNull
    List<Handler> getHandlerChain() {
        return handlerConfig.getHandlerChain();
    }
```

HandlerConfiguration.class:

```
/**
 *
 * @return return a copy of handler chain
 */
public List<Handler> getHandlerChain() {
    if(handlerChain == null)
        return Collections.emptyList();
    return new ArrayList<Handler>(handlerChain);
}
```

So `add()` works (obviously), but not on what you expects.